# Collecting business metrics with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

I am working on a Spring Boot web application project, and I want to be able to collect, and present, some business and performance metrics. For example:

1. What is the mean time that a certain endpoint takes to finish its processing?
2. What are the payloads of an endpoint that resulted on the highest processing time?
3. How many times was an endpoint requested?
4. How many different users accessed the application?
5. Other business metrics, such as the number of likes given globally, or per region, on a social media app.

When searching for metrics and Spring Boot online, I found a lot of material related to Prometheus, [micrometer](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/16/micrometer-spring-boot-2-s-new-application-metrics-collector), actuator, and how it is pretty easy to monitor the application health with this stack. Although, I want to be able to check more than the garbage collector's activity... The metrics I want to collect, for the most part, are not specific to my app, and I wonder if there is anything out there (a more standard solution) to solve this problem, since I believe many people have encountered similar issues.

1. What is the standard solution to collecting metrics like the ones I mentioned?
2. Is there any way to customize the stack given in order for it to collect those metrics?

Comment: When do you refer to endpoint, are you refering to your service endpoint or for some external endpoint consumed by you?

Comment: I am referring to the endpoints on my backend consumed by the frontend of my app.

Comment: I also wanted to supply some custom business metrics about the db record status. Have you found a solution or adopted some approach yourself?